# Run Django on remote server, how can I view in my browser

Tags: mysql, django

I have tried to run my django project on a remote server and it runs perfectly fine. Just wondering how can I view it in my local browser. I have tried `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` and then access the website through `the.remote.server:8000` but it doesn't work and keeps saying 'This site can’t be reached'

Comment: By remote server do you mean a vps on something like DigitalOcean, Amazon, ... or in another computer in your local network, or in a docker container? If you can not view it from your computer how do you have checked that it works fine?

Comment: Most probably port 8000 is blocked. Try to open it with `sudo ufw allow 8000`

Comment: I did ```python manage.py check``` because my only issue is remote mysql database. I can run the program with my local mysql database but can't figure out how to connect to the remote db so I want to try running the program on the remote server directly. The remote server, I mean the server setup by someone else in another computer.

Comment: Are the required ports open in the remote server?

Comment: Yes!! That's the issue. I just ask the owner to open the port and it's working now. Thank you both!